# Detecting enter key C++

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to mask user input and store it in a variable. When I press enter the program should break from the loop, however, the enter key is still registered as a character:

```
#inlcude <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

std::cout << "Password: ";

char c;

// Masks the password
while ((c = _getch()))
{
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        break;
    }

    passwd.push_back(c); // put it onto the back of the password
    _putch('*'); // output a '*' character
}
```

Comment: Try checking for `'\r'` instead.

Comment: I read that \r is used on windows but in combination with \n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On many systems (including Windows), the newline 'character' (`'\n'`) actually represents a combination of two characters: a carriage return (ASCII 13) plus a line-feed (ASCII 10).

For the "Enter" key (which is also *just* the Carriage Return) use the `'\r'` escape sequence:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    std::string passwd;
    std::cout << "Password: ";
    char c;
    // Masks the password
    while ((c = _getch())) {
        if (c == '\r') {
            break;
        }
        passwd.push_back(c); // put it onto the back of the password
        _putch('*'); // output a '*' character
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << passwd << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```